# The Way of the Cross as a Prophecy of the History of the Catholic Church and a Prefigurement of the Fortunes of the Holy See?

Tags: catholicism, church-history, prophecy, papacy, way-of-the-cross

In Fr. F. W. Faber's [*The Precious Blood*](https://ia802601.us.archive.org/21/items/a5807812fabe00uoft/a5807812fabe00uoft.pdf), he makes the statement on p. 279 that:

> Moreover, the Way of the Cross is a great Mystery of prophecy and figure. It is a prophecy of the history of the Church; it is a prefiguring of the fortunes of the Holy See;

[image]

QUESTION: Can someone explain what Fr. Faber may have meant when he said that the Way of the Cross is a prophecy of the history of the Catholic Church and a prefigurement of the fortunes of the Holy See?

Thank you.